# Images Scrolling From Right to Left with CSS only

Tags: css

I have a DIV containing 10 images. I want to scroll this the images in this DIV from Right to Left without using JavaScript. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, not without CSS transitions, which current non-webkit based browsers do not support.

Comment: Actually, they are supported in Firefox too.

Comment: You mean without using scroll bars?

Comment: @Dan they are only supported in Firefox 4 Beta, not the release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: No, you can't do animations using pure CSS, at least not yet. CSS animations and transforms are on the cards, but are not standardised yet, nor widely enough supported to make them worth using.

However, that said, you should have a look at this:

http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css-coke-can/

A clever rolling/scrolling effect using nothing but standard CSS. No Javascript, no CSS-animation or transforms. Very very clever. It even works in IE8.

Of course, it is using some very sneaky CSS tricks to achieve this, so it's not a technique that you'll be using in every-day code. But the question was "is it possible?", not "is it possible without being excessively clever and hacky about it?"

Answer (score 0):

No. As it is now CSS cannot handle animations. You will need to include some sort of javascript to handle this for you. It's not as complicated as you may think though as current frameworks do all the heavy lifting for you. I personally recommend jQuery http://jquery.com/ but there are others out there. There are people who have solved problems like your and created plugins which you should be able to drop onto your site to give you the functionality you require if you aren't sure about creating it yourself http://plugins.jquery.com/

**EDIT**

I should add that while some CSS animation is possible, it will not be supported in some browsers.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/

Credit to Google for the search :)

Like the above comment says, this is CSS3 so you're limited on support for browsers

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using transitions which is a CSS3 feature, so it doesn't work in IE. It does work in ff3.6+ and chrome dunno about the reset of the browsers though, as I didn't have time to test them.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just give that div containing the images a fixed `width` and set the `whitespace: no-wrap` via CSS. Then just add `overflow: auto` to the div, and that should be it.